# Linux install libgdiplus without internet access

Tags: .net, linux, azure, pdf, devexpress

I have a dotnet application that generates PDFs. For this I need to have the libgdiplus library installed on my Linux environment which is in an azure service app. I don’t have internet access on this app service because I am in a private area. So I’m looking for a way to install the libgdiplus library by embedding it for example in the package of my application. Is that possible? How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible to install the libgdiplus library without internet?

No, it is not possible to install the `libgdiplus` library without internet because all the dependencies which we want to install for our application has be downloaded directly from the web with the use of internet only.